# Get the documentclass widths, lengths and spaces

Tags: textpos

I am trying to use the `textpos` package to absolute-position a `textblock` in the upper left corner of the text area on my page (i.e. inside the page margins). I know I can get the width of the text by using `\textwidth`. But what are the corresponding commands to get distances like the left-margin, right-margin, top-margin and bottom-margin?

Comment: Something like `\headheight`, `\footskip`, `\evensidemargin`, `\oddsidemargin`, `\leftmargin`?

Comment: You can use the package [tikzpagenodes][https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes]

Answer (score 3):

The package `layout` will show you all the lengths and their actual values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 2):

You need no measurement, except knowing about `\topskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showboxes]{textpos}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(0pt,-\topskip)
\noindent some text \\ 3cm wide
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer your question, the top left corner of the text block is

```
\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in
\evensidemargin+\hoffset+1in
```

from the left border of the page (depending if on an odd or even page, in `oneside` mode all pages are considered to be odd) and

```
\topmargin+\voffset+\headheight+\headsep+1in
```

from the top border of the page.

The parameters `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are commonly zero and they should remain such: they're thought for small corrections for coping with printing devices and they should never be used for setting the page dimensions.

The `textblock*` environment places the box at the prescribed position, but apparently it doesn't keep into consideration the `\topskip`.

Comment: That's right: `textblock` in relative mode (the default) places boxes relative to the point in the page where the `textblock` is invoked, whereever that happens to be; `textblock` in absolute mode places boxes relative to the top-left of the page.  In each case, it doesn't consider `\topskip` or any other such parameter.